# kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file error

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm using Ruby version 1.9.3 at the moment (although I get the same issue with Ruby 2.0.0). On Windows 7 64-bit.  I'm following 'The Cucumber Book' and got stuck at the chapter 7.2 - "Removing Duplication with Transforms". My folder structure is as follows:

```
\cash_withdrawal
\cash_withdrawal\Gemfile
\cash_withdrawal\Gemfile.lock
\cash_withdrawal\features
\cash_withdrawal\features\cash-withdrawal.feature
\cash_withdrawal\features\step_definitions
\cash_withdrawal\features\step_definitions\cash_withdrawal_steps.rb
\cash_withdrawal\features\step_definitions\lib
\cash_withdrawal\features\step_definitions\lib\nice_bank.rb
\cash_withdrawal\features\support
\cash_withdrawal\features\support\env.rb
\cash_withdrawal\features\support\transforms.rb
\cash_withdrawal\features\support\world_extensions.rb
```

In my `cash_withdrawal_steps.rb` file I have:

```
require 'CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT'

Given /^I have deposited (#{CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT}) in my Account$/ do |amount|
  my_account.deposit(amount)
  my_account.balance.should eq(amount), 
    "Expected the balance to be #{amount} but it was #{my_account.balance}"
end
```

When I run `cucumber` I get:

> C:\Users\Nikita.Harrison\AutomatedTesting\cash_withdrawal>cucumber
>   cannot load such file -- CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT (LoadError)
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `r equire'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   r equire'
>   C:/Users/Nikita.Harrison/AutomatedTesting/cash_withdrawal/features/step_definiti
>   ons/cash_withdrawal_steps.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_l
>   anguage.rb:122:in`load'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_l
>   anguage.rb:122:in `load_code_file'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support
>   _code.rb:180:in`load_file' C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support
>   _code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!' C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support
>   _code.rb:82:in`each' C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support
>   _code.rb:82:in `load_files!' C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:
>   in`load_step_definitions'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:i
>   n `run!'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:
>   in`execute!'
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/cucumber:13:in
>   `<top (re quired)>' C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in`load'
>   C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `'

And if I run `irb` then run `require "CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT"` I get this error:

> irb(main):006:0> require "CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT" LoadError: cannot load
>   such file -- CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
>   e.rb:55:in `require'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
>   e.rb:55:in`require'
>           from (irb):6
>           from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `'

I've tried many fixes including 'require_relative' and nothing seems to solve my problem.
If I remove `require 'CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT'` from the `cash_withdrawal_steps.rb` file and run cucumber then my 'Step Definition' doesn't show as defined:

```
C:\Users\Nikita.Harrison\AutomatedTesting\cash_withdrawal>cucumber
Feature: Cash withdrawal

   @test   Scenario: Successful withdrawal from an account in credit #
 features\cash_with drawal.feature:4
     Given I have deposited $100 in my Account               # features\cash_with drawal.feature:5
     When I withdraw $20                                     # features/step_defi nitions/cash_withdrawal_steps.rb:7
     Then $20 should be dispensed                            # features/step_defi nitions/cash_withdrawal_steps.rb:11
     And the balance of my account should be $80             # features/step_defi nitions/cash_withdrawal_steps.rb:15

 1 scenario (1 undefined) 4 steps (3 skipped, 1 undefined) 0m0.006s

 You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these
 snippets:

 Given(/^I have deposited \$(\d+) in my Account$/) do |arg1|   pending
 \# express the regexp above with the code you wish you had end
```

If I add `require File.join(File.dirname("C:/Users/Nikita.Harrison/AutomatedTesting/cash_withdrawal/features/support"), 'support', 'transforms')` to the `env.rb` file and run `cucumber` I get:

```
 C:/Users/Nikita.Harrison/AutomatedTesting/cash_withdrawal/features/support/trans
 forms.rb:1: warning: already initialized constant CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT
 Feature: Cash withdrawal

   @test   Scenario: Successful withdrawal from an account in credit #
 features\cash_with drawal.feature:4
     Given I have deposited $100 in my Account               # features\cash_with drawal.feature:5
     When I withdraw $20                                     # features/step_defi nitions/cash_withdrawal_steps.rb:7
     Then $20 should be dispensed                            # features/step_defi nitions/cash_withdrawal_steps.rb:11
     And the balance of my account should be $80             # features/step_defi nitions/cash_withdrawal_steps.rb:15

 1 scenario (1 undefined) 4 steps (3 skipped, 1 undefined) 0m0.013s

 You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these
 snippets:

 Given(/^I have deposited \$(\d+) in my Account$/) do |arg1|   pending
 \# express the regexp above with the code you wish you had end
```

I know I must be doing something wrong here but I just can't find out what and need help. 
Gemfile contents:

```
# This Gemfile lists all Gems used throughout the book - with versions.
source :rubygems

# Build stuff
gem 'bundler', '1.5.3'
#gem 'rake', '10.1.1'
#gem 'watchr', '0.7'
#gem 'bcat', '0.6.2'

# General stuff
#gem 'aruba', '0.4.11'
gem 'cucumber', '1.3.10', :require => 'cucumber'
gem 'rake', '10.1.1'
gem 'rspec', '2.14.1', :require => 'cucumber'
gem 'rspec-expectations', '2.14.5'
gem 'watir-webdriver', '0.6.7'
```

I think I've included all the information that is needed.

Answer (score 6):

I just encountered the same issue, and I believe it's a problem with bundler. In any case, I solved the problem by running:

```
bundle update
bundle exec ruby <yourfilename.rb>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems I encountered the same issue before. I fixed it by adding a simple

```
require rubygems
```

before all my require line code.

Comment: Thanks for the info, tried this and it still didn't work. Since then have done the exact same setup on my MacBook Pro and this works with no problems... When I do find the solution to this I will post it but for now I'm still stuck with this issue on Windows but not on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you install a new gem you need to update the bundle (as @zwolfe pointed out).
Hence, run:

`bundle update`

Right after you should be able to run your Ruby scripts either using simply:

`ruby <yourRubyScript.rb>`
or
`bundle exec ruby <yourRubyScript.rb`