# Bundle Update Error - Fix for kernel_require.rb:55:in `require':

Tags: ruby, bundle, require, fxruby

I am have essentially the same issue that the guy has in this question:

[kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831880/kernel-require-rb55in-require-cannot-load-such-file-error)

I am trying to do the bundle fix but I cannot update bundle.

> $ sudo gem install bundle
>   Fetching:
>   bundle-0.0.1.gem (100%)
>   Successfully installed bundle-0.0.1
>   Parsing documentation for bundle-0.0.1
>   Installing ri documentation for bundle-0.0.1 1
>   gem installed
>   $ bundle update
>   Could not locate Gemfile

I have been trying to get fxruby to work and have uninstalled macports and fxruby a few times. I am concerned if bundle was installed by macports at some point and I may have broken it.

Comment: `bundle update` is trying to update the gems in your `Gemfile`. Is that what you want? What are you trying to accomplish with `bundle update`? Update the gem?

Comment: What does make you think you have a problem with kernel_require ?

Comment: @ptd Yes, per the link in the original question that is a fix that was used for kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're issuing `bundle update` right after you installed bundle, so I think you may not yet have a Gemfile in the current directory, which is what your error says:

> Could not locate Gemfile

Check if there is a Gemfile, `cd` in a directory with a Gemfile or create one and try again.

And you should first `bundle install` once you have located / created this Gemfile.